# to merge 2 dataframe in python but make the column remains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge a dataframe in python

```
df 1
Product_Type Product_Colour   Notes
0 Shirt        Black           2 L and 2 S
1 Shirt        Black           1 XL and 2 M
2 Shirt        Black           2 XS and 2 S

df2
   Product_Type Product_Colour   Code
13 Shirt        Black             KI
14 Shirt        Black             KI
25 Shirt        Black             KI

......

that df2 still have many rows. I just want to , if both Product type and colour appears in both df, take the code information and make df3

this is expected result,

Product_Type Product_Colour   Notes             Code
0 Shirt        Black          2 L and 2 S         KI
1 Shirt        Black          1 XL and 2 M        KI
2 Shirt        Black          2 XS and 2 S        KI

but i got this instead
Product_Type Product_Colour   Notes             Code
0 Shirt        Black          2 L and 2 S         KI
```

I did it with `pd.merge(df1,df2 on=['Product_Type','Product_Colour'], how='left')`
It seems that it cannt handle the non-unique value of Product type and Product color.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in the unique values, you could use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function to make `df2` distinct before merging.

```
   df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), how = 'left')
      Product_Type Product_Colour         Notes Code
    0        Shirt          Black   2 L and 2 S   KI
    1        Shirt          Black  1 XL and 2 M   KI
    2        Shirt          Black  2 XS and 2 S   KI
```

complete solution taking the columns into consideration:

```
df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['Product_Type','Product_Colour'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product_Type': ['Shirt', 'Shirt', 'Shirt'],
    'Product_Colour': ['Black', 'Black', 'Black'],
    'Notes': ['2 L and 2 S', '1 XL and 2 M', '2 XS and 2 S']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product_Type': ['Shirt', 'Shirt', 'Shirt'],
    'Product_Colour': ['Black', 'Black', 'Black'],
    'Code': ['KI', 'KI', 'KI']
})

# Group and merge DataFrames
df3 = df1.groupby(['Product_Type', 'Product_Colour'], as_index=False)['Notes'].first()
df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2, on=['Product_Type', 'Product_Colour'], how='left')

print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  Product_Type Product_Colour          Notes Code
0        Shirt          Black   2 L and 2 S   KI
1        Shirt          Black  1 XL and 2 M   KI
2        Shirt          Black  2 XS and 2 S   KI
```